# Removing/replacing brackets from R string using gsub

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I want to remove or replace brackets "(" or ")" from my string using gsub. However as shown below it is not working. What could be the reason?

```
 >  k<-"(abc)"
 >  t<-gsub("()","",k)
 >  t 
[1] "(abc)"
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using the correct regex works:

```
gsub("[()]", "", "(abc)")
```

The additional square brackets mean *"match any of the characters inside"*.

Answer (score 2):

A safe and simple solution that doesn't rely on regex:

```
k <- gsub("(", "", k, fixed = TRUE) # "Fixed = TRUE" disables regex
k <- gsub(")", "", k, fixed = TRUE)
k
[1] "abc"
```

Answer (score 1):

The possible way could be (in the line OP is trying) as:

```
gsub("\\(|)","","(abc)")
#[1] "abc"


`\(`  => look for `(` character. `\` is needed as `(` a special character. 
`|`  =>  OR condition 
`)` =   Look for `)`
```