# How to remove "()" from data frame cells?

Tags: r, string, substring

I am trying to clean my data from a data frame's cells. I want to remove some strings, but `gsub` somehow omits "()". My code:

```
getridof <- c("(a)", "(40X)", "(5X)", "(10X_a)", "(10X)", "(_)")

for (i in 1:length(getridof)) {
  df2$Sample <- gsub(getridof[i], "", df2$Sample)  
}
```

but "()" is left in cells after executing the script?

Comment: have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49681981/8689518
maybe it helps?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing/replacing brackets from R string using gsub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49681952/removing-replacing-brackets-from-r-string-using-gsub)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `gsub`:

```
gsub("[()]", "", getridof)

[1] "a"     "40X"   "5X"    "10X_a" "10X"   "_"
```

Using `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
str_remove_all(getridof, "[()]")

[1] "a"     "40X"   "5X"    "10X_a" "10X"   "_"
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution, but I am not sure whether you only want to remove parentheses:

```r
library(tidyverse)

getridof <- c("(a)", "(40X)", "(5X)", "(10X_a)", "(10X)", "(_)")

getridof %>% 
  str_remove("^\\(") %>% 
  str_remove("\\)$") 

#> [1] "a"     "40X"   "5X"    "10X_a" "10X"   "_"
```

Taking the alternative interpretation of your question:

```r
library(tidyverse)

getridof <- c("(a)", "(40X)", "(5X)", "(10X_a)", "(10X)", "(_)")
data <- c("(a)100", "(40X)33", "nothing", "zzzz(5X)", "22(10X_a)44", "yyy(10X)", "aa(_)b")

getridof <- getridof %>% 
  str_replace("\\(", "\\\\(") %>% 
  str_replace("\\)", "\\\\)") %>% 
  str_c(collapse = "|")
  
str_replace_all(data, getridof, "")

#> [1] "100"     "33"      "nothing" "zzzz"    "2244"    "yyy"     "aab"
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! I want the whole strings removed with "(" and ")" as well, not just the brackets. But your solution will be useful for me in some other cases. However, I don't get the tidyverse syntax

Comment: If you add a minimal example of your `df2$Sample`, we will be able to offer you a full solution, @mschmidt.

Answer (score 1):

This uses `reduce` and the `fixed = TRUE` argument of `gsub`:

```r
library(purrr)
data <- c("(a)100", "(40X)33", "nothing")

getridof <- c("(a)", "(40X)", "(5X)", "(10X_a)", "(10X)", "(_)")

purrr::reduce(getridof,
              ~gsub(.y, "", .x, fixed = TRUE),
              .init = data)

# [1] "100"     "33"      "nothing"
```

The `purrr::reduce` function is meant to replace your for loop. It recursively delete each of the unwanted strings from `data`.

Answer (score 0):

adding argument `fixed = TRUE` did the job

```
df2$Sample <- gsub(getridof[i], "", df2$Sample, fixed = TRUE)
```